# How to pass a variable number of arguments to ant exec

Tags: java, ant

I have a ant target that takes a variable number of arguments that are to be passed to an exec task. Using the old mechanism it is trivial:

```
<exec command="cmd /c ${_full-path-to-exec}" osfamily="windows" failonerror="true">
</exec>
```

However, use of 'command' is deprecated in favor of nested  elements. like this:

```
<exec executable="cmd" osfamily="windows" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg file="${_full-path-to-exec}"/>
    <arg value="${_param-one}"/>
    <arg value="${_param-two}"/>
    <arg value="${_param-three}"/>
</exec>
```

which makes variable argument lists impossible.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this:

```
 <arg line="whatever args you need"/>
```

Comment: mutter, mutter, mutter ... where did the hell did that come from? I swear to god I have looked at that doc multiple times and never saw that d*$&m attribute. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually the first example on exec ant page. No worries, it happens to all of us :)

Comment: This is all very well however there are use cases where one has to use the `value` attribute of the `arg` element because the `line` attribute will not do. They are not always interchangeable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9562235/274677