# Set system properties using ant

Tags: java, ant, properties

I know that a properties file can be loaded in ant using

```
<property file="${path_to_properties_file}"/>
```

But how to set this as system properties so that it can be accessed in java code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi maybe this can help you? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/SetsystempropertiesinAntbuildscript.htm

Comment: How are you running your java code? such as java task or custom task?

Comment: I am running as custom task,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ant, jvmarg, system properties and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532306/ant-jvmarg-system-properties-and-quotes)